# Unique/Shared ptr to automatically delete array after it goes out of scope

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to improve my skills in C++.Suppose that i have the following piece of code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int *p;
    p=new int[10];
    delete [] p;
    return 0;
}
```

How can i use unique/shared ptr to automatically delete the array instead of doing it manually when it goes out of scope in this piece of code?BTW i have read in SO that i might need to download boost library to use a unique/shared ptr.Can anyone confirm this?Or is it included in std libraries?

Comment: You are going to need some [good resources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Please head over there now.

Comment: @WhiZTiM Thanks,in fact i have the book Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++ which was written by Bjarne Stroupstrup and it is a really good book,but it is quite hard to understand after some chapters.

Answer (score 4):

There is `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` in C++11, which allows you to do this:

```
std::unique_ptr<int[]> p(new int[10]);
```

If you want a compile-time constant array, you can use `std::array` instead:

```
std::array<int, 10> p;
```

Otherwise, just pick the good old `std::vector` instead:

```
std::vector<int> p(10);
```

Comment: "*But `unique_ptr` is not suited for arrays and you shouldn't use it for them*" - that statement is misleading. `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` is *specifically designed* for arrays (it even exposes an `operator[]` for indexing). It works just fine.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Fair enough, thanks for the edit too, what I meant was that it's unusual.

Answer (score 3):

Since C++11, `std::unique_ptr` is included in the Standard Library.  You can do:

```
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<int[]> p( new int[10] );
}
```

By the way, [`using namespace std;` is a bad habit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) to get into.

You might also consider using `std::vector<int>` instead of `std::unique_ptr<int[]>`.

Comment: Is it bad using namespace std in general or only in header files?I always use using namespace std only in .cpp files and never in .h.

Comment: @JohnM. it is bad in general.

Comment: @JohnM. It's slightly *less bad* to use it in .cpp files than it is to use it in .h files, but it's still bad. The ideal is self-documenting code, whereby it's easy for anyone reading the code to immediately know what's going on, and where your types are derived from, and `using namespace std;` harms that, regardless of whether you're polluting namespaces with it (in .h files) or not (in .cpp files).